# Global Scope Attached Dependency Property

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, dependency-properties

I would like to do something like a static variable in normal programming, only in XAML using Dependency Properties.

Meaning I would like the property to :

- Be one instance
- Be visible by every element
- Be bindable

How do I do that ?

Comment: Something wrong with StaticResource?

Comment: @GazTheDestroyer "Be bindable" is a requirement... assuming this means two-way binding, resources won't do.

Comment: Please refrain from using `code formatting` to highlight things you `think` are `important`.  It's for code, not for emphasis.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you want an attached property that always applies to every element. I think the easiest way to make that work would be through the [CoerceValueCallback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.coercevaluecallback%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of the dependency property, where you could force it to always return the static value regardless of the element's local value (you would update the static value in the [PropertyChangedCallback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.propertychangedcallback%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)).

This seems like an odd way to use the dependency property system, though. Maybe you just need a central binding source? You can bind to a static instance by assigning `Binding.Source` using `x:Static`:

```
{Binding Source={x:Static Member=global:GlobalObject.SharedInstance},
         Path=SharedValue}
```

Note that `SharedValue` isn't a static property; it's a property of an instance accessed from the static `SharedInstance` property:

```
public class GlobalObject {
    private static readonly GlobalObject _instance = new GlobalObject();

    public static GlobalObject SharedInstance { get { return _instance; } }

    public object SharedValue { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Easy.

Create an [attached DependencyProperty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on the DependencyObject Type.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty DerpProperty = 
  DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
  "Derp",
  typeof(DependencyObject),
  typeof(Herp),
  new FrameworkPropertyMetadata());

public static void SetDerp(DependencyObject element, Herp value)
{
    element.SetValue(DerpProperty, value);
}

public static Herp GetDerp(DependencyObject element)
{
    return (Herp)element.GetValue(DerpProperty);
}
```

Defined on any type, it can be used on any type as well.  In this example, it creates a new property called **Derp** on all `DependencyObject` instances that gets/sets an associated **Herp** value.

Assuming this is defined in a type called `LolKThx` in the namespace `WpfFtw`, you might use it in this way...

```
<Textblock 
    xmlns:lol="clr-namespace:WpfFtw" 
    lol:LolKThx.Derp="There's an implicit conversion for string -> Herp, btw" />
```

You can specify callbacks in your `FrameworkPropertyMetadata` to perform any action you need on setting/getting values.